# Covariant return type with non-pointer/reference return type

Tags: c++, pointers, ienumerable, return-type, covariant

I'm trying to implement a .NET framework like collection class in C++(11). My problem is an invalid covariant type. I have these classes:

```
template<typename T>
class IEnumerator
{
public:
    virtual bool MoveNext() = 0;
    //...
};

template<typename T>
class IEnumerable
{
    virtual IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class List : public IEnumerable<T>
{
public:
    struct Enumerator : public IEnumerator<T>
    {
        Enumerator(List<T> &list)
        {
            //...
        }
        // ...
    };

    Enumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Enumerator(*this);
    }
};
```

According to me, this is awesome. But it looks impossible to implement it in C++. I get the "Invalid covariant return type" by g++, and as far as I read, the problem is that GetEnumerator might only return a pointer or a reference to Enumerator, and not an object of Enumerator itself.

I'd like to avoid returning a pointer like this:

```
Enumerator *GetEnumerator()
{
    return new Enumerator(*this);
}
```

because I don't want the caller to bother deleting. Using the temporary object I'd be sure that the object is deleted automatically as it isn't needed anymore. Using references might be even worse.

Am I missing something? Or is there a huge hole in the C++ standard (and language)? I'd really like to achieve something like this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Gah! `IEnumerable` is a poor reinvention of C++ iterators; why would you want it in C++? In any case, .NET uses reference semantics, so to mimic that in C++, you must use references or pointers -- no surprise here.

Comment: This is impossible to implement in a value language.

Comment: @ildjarn I find it nice so that I can use IEnumerable in function arguments, and whatever is the type behind (a vector, a linked list, an RB-tree) it is still IEnumerable, it has a GetEnumerator() function which returns an IEnumerator. Can you pass both vector<t> and list<t> to the same function without common ancestors?

Comment: @AlfaOmega08: Yes, you can write a function (template) that will take either a `list<T>` and a `vector<T>` without any problems -- but you almost never should. Instead, it should normally take a pair of iterators (or a range). The standard library has many examples (e.g., `std::accumulate`, `std::sort`, `std::find`, `std::lower_bound`, etc.)

Comment: @AlfaOmega08 : Yes, of course -- as a template. `IEnumerable` (non-generic) works because of `System.Object`, of which there is no corollary in C++. `IEnumerable<>` (generic) uses runtime generics -- templates can be viewed as compile-time generics, and you'll notice that every standard library algorithm that works with iterators is a template.

Comment: @JerryCoffin my bad, I didn't tink about the pair of iterators :|

Comment: As an aside, a safe alternative to returning new'd T*'s that your caller has to delete, you can return std::shared_ptr<T>, which will auto delete when all references are defunct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>Covariant value return types cannot be implemented. The problem is that it is the responsibility of the caller to allocate space in the stack for the returned object and the amount of space required for a covariant value return would be unknown at compile time.</strike>

This works seamlessly with pointers/references as the returned object is the pointer or reference (rather than the actual derived object), and the size is known at compile time.

After a rather absurd (on my side) discussion with @curiousguy I must backtrack from the previous answer. There is not technical issue that would make covariant value return types impossible. On the other hand, it would have different negative effects:

From a design perspective, the returned object would have to be *sliced* if called from base (this is where the size of the returned object matters). This is a clear difference from the current model, in the current model the function *always* returns the *same* object, it is only the reference or pointer that changes types. But the actual *object* is the same.

In the general case, covariant value types would inhibit some of the copy-elision optimizations. Currently, many calling conventions, for a function that returns by value, dictate that the caller passes a pointer to the location of the returned object. That allows the caller to reserve the space of the variable that will hold the value, and then pass that pointer on. The callee can then use that pointer to construct in place of the object that will hold the value in the caller context and no copies will be required. With covariant value returned types and because the most derived object created by the final overrider must be destroyed to avoid undefined behavior. The caller would pass a pointer to a location in memory, the trampoline function would have to reserve space for the returned object of the final overrider, then it would need to *slice-copy* from that second object to the first, incurring the cost of a copy.

At any rate, the actual *cost* of the operation would not be as much of an issue as the fact that the semantics of the call to the final overrider would be different<sup>*</sup> depending on what the static type of the reference through which the call is performed.

---

<sup>*</sup> This is already the case with the current language definition. For all non-virtual functions, if the derived type *hides* a member function on the base, then the static type of the returned pointer/reference (which in turn depends on the static type used to call the virtual function) will affect what function gets actually called and the behavior differs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15305/discussion-between-curiousguy-and-david-rodriguez-dribeas)

Comment: "_I already told you that you were right regarding the virtual functions, which implies_" OK, implied apologies. Interesting concept. "_That being said, you have a problem of attitude, and reading_" No, you have one. "_You still have not understood the nitpick of the 2-phase lookup._" I understand that you were trolling.

Comment: "_You have just said in a comment that sometimes decisions are not backed and are arbitrary (contrary to what you stated before, but let it go)._" **Decisions do not come from nowhere.** Committee members have various things in mind when they vote (sometimes, they take the same decision for different reasons). There is a documented motive (in WG21 documents) for most committee decision. (In D&E for pre-std process decisions.) When I said "x is an arbitrary restriction" I meant that you cannot justify the restriction base on other more fundamental design decisions.

Comment: Sometimes people just fear that generalization of a feature would complicate matter too much. Sometimes people just don't have time to evaluate the consequences of a generalization. The committee had lots of difficult issues to consider. From experience **many people think that trying to generalize things as much as possible is dangerous, and  often leads to complicated half-baked designs**. See STL allocators for an example of what most of the committee considered in 1997 as a complete design disaster, trying to generalize not only `malloc` but also pointers, references, etc.

Comment: **I used the term "arbitrary" for a choice that was not logical consequence of another more fundamental choice.** Maybe my use of that word was not always consistent, but I think within context it was extremely clear.

Comment: "_But your answer says otherwise: There is a reason besides "the standard says so"._" Yes, there is; others, absolutely correct answers on this often asked question just quoted the standard saying "dependent base classes are not searched". It answers the question "is that allowed in C++", but raises another question "why is that not allowed in C++?" as the rule seems to come from nowhere, it seems like an arbitrary **and extremely stupid** design decision.

Comment: I explained that the fundamental reason is the way lookup is done **in general**. The rules for lookup in dependent base classes are a consequence of general rules for name lookup in templates. Your points seems to be that 1) I didn't explained that the lookup rules are called "2 phase name lookup". 2) "templates are just macros" is a viable alternative to "2 phase name lookup".

Comment: While I really don't like the "templates are just macros" approach, I have previously said that "2 phase name lookup" is annoying, creates many problem (like this one) and **does not even fix the problem it's supposed to fix in the first place** (name capture: locality of names is not respected). I am not alone. **Most of the committee members I know have been saying exact the same thing. The only fix for the underlying problem is concepts. (Oops.)**

Comment: "_So is it arbitrary and just because the standard says so, or is there an underlying reason?_" If you understand the design of C++, you know that **"2 phase name lookup" is necessary to avoid some cases of name capture**. It cannot do much, but at least it can avoid picking up type names in the template specialization context. Few people says that, but **C++ is a broken language**. It is all about the level of brokenness you can accept.

Comment: "2 phase name lookup" = still broken and complicated and surprising rules. "templates are just macros" = even more broken name lookup cases (name picked from the instantiation context), but simple rules =  more similarity between templates and non-templates.

Comment: @curiousguy: You keep putting words in my mouth (or rather keyboard). *Templates are just macros*, and there is no need for 2 phases of lookup are completely unrelated. Using your own form of assumptions on the ignorance of others I could add that you have no idea of anything related to templates (which would be false, as many similar statements you did about me).Do you *really* think that the only difference between the current definition and *templates are just macros*? Or are you just trolling now? --I don't think I need to provide *again* counter examples.

Comment: "_You keep putting words in my mouth (or rather keyboard)._" That was *not* my intent. If you don't have "Templates are just macros" or "2 phases of lookup", what kind of lookup rules do you want for templates? I don't know what other alternatives exist. "_I don't think I need to provide again counter examples_" You don't need to again troll me with your "counter examples".

Comment: @curiousguy: Neither D nor VS implement *templates are just macros*. Templates are not *substitution* at all, they represent a turing complete functional sublanguage executed at compile time. As a matter of fact if some of the proposals to the standard go forward (particularly `static if`) more and more of the template features will be forced to be evaluated during the second phase of lookup, and the language will at the same time be less *substitution* and a richer language as more powerful primitives would be available.

Comment: "_Neither D nor VS implement templates are just macros._" What do they implement? "_Templates are not substitution at all, they represent a turing complete functional sublanguage_" so is the C preprocessor.

Comment: @curiousguy: Just mention a single thing that can be done with two-phase lookup that could not be done with only the second phase. When lookup is executed does not limit the expressiveness of the language at all, it just affects the need of `typename` and `template` here and there, and the need for *extra* qualifications/`this` to force a name to become *dependent*. The two alternatives only differ on *meaning* when a name could be interpreted differently in the context of the template or in a dependent context.

Comment: ... if you really think that without two-phase lookup templates become just glorified macros then your understanding of templates is closer to *generics* as understood in C# or Java than to what templates really are. Consider for example template specializations, including partial specializations, SFINAE...

Comment: @curiousguy they want to you join the Lounge: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/4994825#4994825

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Yes but last time it was a trap, and there was an angry mob.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename T>
class IEnumerable
{
    virtual IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() = 0;
};
```

You are trying to **return a `IEnumerable<T>` but it is an abstract base class**: it means you promise to construct an object of a class that cannot be instantiated!

Only **concrete classes** derived from an abstract base class can be instantiated.

You probably intended to return a pointer to such object. Anyway, this is bad design. You do not need to emulate Java in C++.

Answer (score 0):

You just don't do things like that in C++ unless you're using pointers.  The .net guys use references so it's pretty much the same stuff.

In C++ you would more likely implement this with concepts rather than inheritance.  You should be reviewing "generic programming" ideas.  The boost website has a decent introduction: http://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html